# net err connection timed out

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-12.04, proxypass

I have Apache/2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04. Apache is set as reverse proxy server. 
So when accessed from a remote system, the page and contents are 
displayed. But after some time the server seems to refuse any further 
requests. The remote browser console gives "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
error.  But when the ip of the remote machine changes (using a dongle which changes ip after
every connect/disconnect), the page/contents displays again. 
But the above said issues occur again.

Their is tomcat7 running along with apache. Tomcat is serving the jsf page through port 8080. All the other requests are handled by apache, proxy it to 
a virtual machine.

In `apache2.conf` file i mainly looked/changed these directives

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 2
Include proxy.conf

ServerLimit     350
StartServers     20
MinSpareServers  75
MaxSpareServers 150
MaxClients      320
```

In `proxy.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
    ServerName server_name  
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cartodb_error.log
LogLevel debug
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cartodb_custom.log combined


<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://cartodb.user:3002 
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ maxattempts=10000000
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

<VirtualHost *:8182>
ServerName server_name
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/windshaft_error.log
LogLevel debug
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/windshaft_custom.log combined

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://cartodb.user:8182
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ maxattempts=10000000
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```

also similar VirtualHost directives with port 8082, 8889 with similar settings.
The "cartodb.user" has been aded in the /etc/hosts file to redirect it to virtual box.
Also the firewall has been disabled for the virtualbox. virtual box is also having
Ubuntu 12.04.

In `ports.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8889
NameVirtualHost *:8082
NameVirtualHost *:8182
NameVirtualHost *:3000
Listen 80
Listen 8889
Listen 8082
Listen 8182
Listen 3000
```

The enabled modules are

```
actions.conf,actions.load,alias.conf,alias.load,authz_host.load,
cache.load,cgid.conf,cgid.load,proxy_ajp.load,proxy_balancer.conf,
proxy_balancer.load,proxy.conf,proxy_connect.load,proxy_ftp.conf,proxy_ftp.load,
proxy_html.conf,proxy_html.load,proxy_http.load,proxy.load,
proxy_scgi.load,rewrite.load
```

On reqtimeout.conf

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500
```

Checked the Apache log files didn't give any error when `LogLevel` is put in debug. Please point out how to avoid this situation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use another browser?
As your error message is not a usual Webserver / Application error please try another browser first.

Another possible explanation might be that your webserver is not able to take anymore connections. You could check this by enabling mod_status

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case the apache configuration is not the problem.
The problem is the network where the server is, in my case I use the AWS.
The ips from my server was not configured as "Elastic IPs" and gave this problem, only change was to "Elastic IP" and the problem is over.